# Converting Cartesian Components of a Vector on a Sphere to Tangential-Normal Components

Tags: geometry, vector-analysis, classical-mechanics

I am dealing with a mechanics problem on a unit sphere where all the equations are written in terms of Cartesian components and wish to make a conversion to a system $n, t, s$ where $n$ is the unit normal to the surface, $t$ is tangential to the surface and $s$ is also tangential to the surface and orthogonal to $n$ and $t$.

In theory, this should be easy for a sphere because the normal vector is the same as the radial vector, then you can take the cross product of the normal vector and the unit vector in the $z$ direction to get the tangent vector.

$\textbf{t}     = \textbf{n} \: \times \: \hat{\textbf{k}}. $

The second tangential vector is then obtained via

$ \textbf{s}     = \textbf{n} \: \times \: \textbf{t}.  $

This seems fine, but then say, I have a radial vector with Cartesian components $[r_x \: r_y \: r_z]^T$, but now I want it to have the equivalent tangential-normal components $[r_n \: r_t \: r_s]^T$, so what would the formula be to take the $x$, $y$ and $z$ components and convert them, as there will no longer be a formula to convert as there would be with Cartesian to spherical polar coordinates, for example.

Edit: Added example of conversion.

$\begin{bmatrix}
    r_{x}       \\
    r_{y}      \\
    r_{z}    
\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}
  n_x    &  t_x  & s_x \\
    n_y      &  t_y & s_y \\
   n_z     & t_z  & s_z
\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}
    r_{n}       \\
    r_{t}      \\
    r_{s}    
\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}
  \cos \theta    &  -\sin \theta & 0 \\
    \sin \theta     &  \cos \theta & 0 \\
  0   & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
    r_{n}       \\
    r_{t}      \\
    r_{s}    
\end{bmatrix}$

Edit: Should the matrix giving the conversion actually be:

$\begin{bmatrix}
    r_{x}       \\
    r_{y}      \\
    r_{z}    
\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}
 \sin \theta \cos \phi   & \sin \phi &  \cos \theta \cos \phi \\
 \sin \theta \sin \phi      & - \cos \phi &  \cos \theta \sin \phi\\
 \cos \phi    & 0  &- \sin \theta
\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}
    r_{n}       \\
    r_{t}      \\
    r_{s}   
    \end{bmatrix} $

Comment: Your new reference system varies depending on the point you choose on the sphere, which usually is the point where the vector is applied. Hence you must also supply the coordinates of that point.

Comment: So for example, if I specify the vector $[0 \: 0 \: 1]$ in Cartesian components?  Since the system depends on the point, could I have conversion as above in terms of the rotation matrix about the $z$ axis in three dimensions?

Comment: Maybe this will help: every point in space can be labeled with an $(x,y,z)$ label. And each of those points has an $\hat{x}$, $\hat{y}$, and $\hat{z}$ direction. In a different labeling system, every point in space can be labeled with an $(n, t, s)$ label. And each of those points in space has an $\hat{n}$, $\hat{t}$, and $\hat{s}$ direction. Given an $(x_1, y_1, z_1)$ and an $(x_2, y_2, z_2)$, it's really easy to tell someone what their displacement vector is. In the new system given an equivalent $(n_1, t_1, s_1)$ corresponding to the same $(x_1, y_1, z_1)$ and an $(n_2, t_2, s_2)$ it would

Comment: be really difficult, if someone were at $(n_1, t_1, s_1)$, to give them directions to general second point. Our brains our wired for cartesian direction giving. But it would be really simply to give someone directions, starting from $(0, \text{undefined}, \text{undefined})$, i.e. the origin, to $(n_2, t_2, s_2)$. You tell them to go in the direction $n_2 \hat{n}(t_2,s_2)$. All points on a sphere, with radius $R$, are given by $R \hat{r}$. It's confusing because cartesian directions are always constant. spherical directions are functions

Comment: I consider $(x,y,z)$ different from $[x,y,z]^T$ which means to me something like $x\hat{x} + y\hat{y} + z\hat{z}$. The first is a point and the second is a vector in my head. An $(x,y,z)$ has an equivalent $(n,t,s)$. But an $x\hat{x} + y\hat{y} + z\hat{z}$, a position vector, always just corresponds to a position vector $n \hat{n}$ ($\hat{n}$ is a function. I don't know the direction of $\hat{n}$ unless you tell me the $t,s$ coordinates of the $(x,y,z)$ point)

Comment: Yes, I know how Cartesian and spherical polar coordinates work, I just need a formula which converts components of a radial vector in Cartesian coordinates to components in the tangential-normal system.  I don't necessarily need to be able to move from one point to another, I just need to be able to specify the position of each point, this is just for the particular problem I am working on.

Comment: I'm not following the answer already given (it's probably right - I'm just easily confused), but given a position vector $x\hat{x} + y\hat{y} + z\hat{z}$ the vector you are looking for is $\sqrt{x^2 + y^2 + z^2} \hat{n}$. The position vector in the new system just has 1 component. With $\hat{n} = \sin\theta\cos\phi \hat{x} + \sin\theta\sin\phi \hat{y} + \cos\theta \hat{z}$ from the way I read the question/comment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $(\sin\theta\cos\phi,\sin\theta\sin\phi,\cos\theta)$ be the coordinates of the reference point on the sphere. From your definitions it follows that the components of $\hat n$, $\hat t$, $\hat s$ in cartesian coordinates are given by:

$$
\hat n=(\sin\theta\cos\phi,\sin\theta\sin\phi,\cos\theta),\quad
\hat t=(\sin\phi,-\cos\phi,0),\quad
\hat s=(\cos\theta\cos\phi,\cos\theta\sin\phi,-\sin\theta).
$$
(Notice that here $\hat t={1\over\sin\theta}\hat n\times\hat z$, to obtain a
unit vector).

Suppose then you have a vector $v_{nts}=(v_n,v_t,v_s)$ expressed in $nts$ coordinates. From the above formulas it follows that its cartesian components are given by 
$v_{xyz}=Mv_{nts}$, where:
$$
M=\pmatrix
{\sin\theta\cos\phi & \sin\phi & \cos\theta\cos\phi \\
\sin\theta\sin\phi & -\cos\phi & \cos\theta\sin\phi \\
\cos\theta & 0 & -\sin\theta}.
$$
And of course: $v_{nts}=M^{-1}v_{xyz}$.

Comment: Just to check in the middle of the matrix, that should be $- \sin \theta \cos \phi$ I think

Comment: As I wrote, $\hat n\times\hat z$ is not a unit vector: its length is $\sin\theta$. To obtain a unit vector I defined $\hat t=(\hat n\times\hat z)/\sin\theta$.

Comment: Apologies, yes I was reading it wrong.

Comment: I think your idea is right, but some of the rows might need to be switched around.  You have it so the whole normal vector goes into the top row, I have done it as I think it should be in the answer.

Comment: Because you need for example, $r_x = n_x r_n + t_x r_t + s_x r_s$ for the system, for example.

Comment: You have in your matrix $M$ \begin{bmatrix}
  n_x    &  n_y  & n_z\\
    t_x     &  t_y & t_z \\
   s_x   & s_y & s_z
\end{bmatrix}

Comment: Does it not need to be \begin{bmatrix}
  n_x    &  t_x  & s_x \\
    n_y      &  t_y & s_y \\
   n_z     & t_z  & s_z
\end{bmatrix}

Comment: You are right: it should be the transpose of $M$. I'll correct the answer.

Comment: Could I ask for an example, for example what would the unit vector along the $z$ axis $[0 0 1]^T$ become in this new coordinate system?

Comment: We have: $$
M^{-1}=\pmatrix
{\sin\theta\cos\phi & \sin\theta\sin\phi & \cos\theta \\ \sin\phi&-\cos\phi&0\\
\cos\theta\cos\phi & \cos\theta\sin\phi & -\sin\theta}.
$$
Hence the transformed of $(0,0,1)^T$ is $$M^{-1}\pmatrix{0\\0\\1}=\pmatrix{\cos\theta\\0\\-\sin\theta}.$$

Comment: One thing I am not sure about, how would you define the tangent to the north and south poles?  Obviously the definition I have no longer works, as the normal vector and the unit vector along the z axis point in the same direction, so the vector product will evaluate to 0.

Comment: At poles you can simply take $\hat x$ and $\hat y$ as tangent vectors.